# How to get value only visible and checked from checkbox via javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

How to get value only visible and checked from checkbox via javascript ?

https://jsfiddle.net/ytbvd6px/1/

from html code. It's have 3 checked checkbox and 1 `diaplay : none` on checkbox value = 3

when press button, I want to get value only visible and checked checkbox. in this case i want to alert `1-4-`

How can i do ?

```
<script>
function test_fn(){
    var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('test_name[]');
    var len = cboxes.length;
    var pack_value = '';
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if(cboxes[i].checked != false)
        {
            pack_value += cboxes[i].value+"-";
        }
    }

    alert(pack_value);    
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add `cboxes[i].style.display != 'none'` in your `if` condition like below
`if (cboxes[i].checked != false && cboxes[i].style.display != 'none')`
[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ytbvd6px/2/)